# Recieving "404, Not Found" when making API call to Pardot from Salesforce, How can we resolve this?

Tags: api, pardot

I'm able to fetch the API key but when I use the same API to fetch the results from Pardot I'm able to fetch them in the POSTMAN and not in the Sales cloud.

When I make the API call to Pardot with the below mentioned request from Sales cloud, it gives "404 not found" in return.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://pi.pardot.com//api/visitorActivity/version/4/do/query?prospect_only=true');
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Authorization','Pardot api_key=00f524626a74a503s475480201212494, user_key=bz2a123a756befba12345679cf47efe4');
req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');

    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
    System.debug(res.getStatus());
```

the above mentioned code returns the status as **System.HttpResponse[Status=Not Found, StatusCode=404]**

Please let me know if there is anything I need to do to get the correct result or do any configuration in the Pardot or Sales cloud org as well.

Comment: you have those two '/' in api ".com//api/v" try removing them

Comment: @User6670, this does not work. The above mentioned request is working from Postman but not from Salesforce.

Comment: strange i used the above code in anonymous window after removing that '/' and i got status as 200 OK

Comment: @User6670, Thanks for the information. I tried this out and it worked for me.